# Compiling OpenVAS-SMB on Debian Stretch

Tags: linux, compiler-errors, debian, samba, openvas

I'm trying to build the OpenVAS-SMB plugin on Debian Stretch from source, but it fails, although it builds successfully with the same prerequisites on Debian Jessie.

CMake confirms all required dependencies before starting to build:

```
root@xxxx:/home/xxxx/openvas-smb-1.0.2# cmake . && make
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 6.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 6.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found Perl: /usr/bin/perl (found version "5.24.1")
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29")
-- Checking for module 'popt'
--   Found popt, version 1.16
-- Found Popt: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpopt.so
-- Found GSSAPI: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so
-- Install prefix: /usr/local
-- Checking for module 'gnutls>=3.2.15'
--   Found gnutls, version 3.5.8
-- Checking for module 'glib-2.0'
--   Found glib-2.0, version 2.50.3
-- Found GnuTLS: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so (found version "3.5.8")
-- Looking for xmltoman...
-- Looking for xmltoman... /usr/bin/xmltoman
-- Looking for xmlmantohtml... /usr/bin/xmlmantohtml
-- Found Doxygen: /usr/bin/doxygen (found version "1.8.13")
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
```

It builds samba and the libs correctly, but fails when it comes to winexe:

```
../samba/libsamba-static.a(kerberos.c.o): In function `kerberos_kinit_password_cc':
kerberos.c:(.text+0x124): undefined reference to `krb5_get_init_creds_opt_init'
kerberos.c:(.text+0x133): undefined reference to `krb5_get_init_creds_opt_set_default_flags'
kerberos.c:(.text+0x153): undefined reference to `krb5_get_init_creds_password'
kerberos.c:(.text+0x182): undefined reference to `krb5_cc_initialize'
kerberos.c:(.text+0x196): undefined reference to `krb5_cc_store_cred'
kerberos.c:(.text+0x1d2): undefined reference to `krb5_free_cred_contents'
kerberos.c:(.text+0x1e7): undefined reference to `krb5_free_cred_contents'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
winexe/CMakeFiles/winexe.dir/build.make:186: recipe for target 'winexe/winexe' failed
make[2]: *** [winexe/winexe] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:145: recipe for target 'winexe/CMakeFiles/winexe.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [winexe/CMakeFiles/winexe.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:149: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I'm guessing that there's an issue with either heimdal-dev or the libglib2.0-dev causing this.

These are the requirements for building OpenVAS-SMB besides the typical build tools: gcc-mingw-w64 libgnutls28-dev perl-base heimdal-dev heimdal-multidev libpopt-dev libglib2.0-dev

Anyone know of any differences between the libs that could make the build fail on Stretch, but work on Jessie? Or maybe can provide a hint on how to do further troubleshooting?

Thanks!

Comment: We need to see the `ld` command used when the error ***`../samba/libsamba-static.a(kerberos.c.o) ... kerberos_kinit_password_cc:`*** happens. Unfortunately, Cmake hides that useful information from you.

Comment: I assume this is what you're looking for: openvas-smb-1.0.2/winexe/CMakeFiles/winexe.dir # cat link.txt
/usr/bin/cc  -Wno-unused-result -fno-strict-aliasing -fPIC -O2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector    CMakeFiles/winexe.dir/winexe.c.o CMakeFiles/winexe.dir/service.c.o CMakeFiles/winexe.dir/async.c.o CMakeFiles/winexe.dir/winexesvc_exe.c.o  -o winexe -rdynamic ../samba/libsamba-static.a -ldl -lgnutls -lcom_err -lpopt -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now